# Integrating AWS analytics to Swift Application

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services

I am currently working on an iOS app using app. I want to add AWS mobile analytics to my app but I've been having a difficult time doing so. I followed AWS get started guide but it doesn't work. I imported AWS using Cocoapods. 
In the guide, the code to initialize AWS mobile analytics is here (it is in objective-C) :

```
AWSMobileAnalytics *analytics = [AWSMobileAnalytics mobileAnalyticsForAppId: @"myAppID" 
        identityPoolId: @"myIdentityPool iD"];
```

I don't know much about objective-C, but I translated it to swift like this:

```
var analytics: AWSMobileAnalytics = AWSMobileAnalytics(mobileAnalyticsForAppI:"myAppID", identityPoolId: "myIdentityPool iD")
```

When I went back to the aws analytics dashboard, nothing showed up. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you apply "PutEvent" IAM policy to your user?

Comment: I don't think so, How do I do that? I am really sorry I am very new to AWS.

Comment: You have a cognate identity pool for you app right?

Comment: I recommend you try out AWS Mobile Hub https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/
It gives a working sample app for your preferred iOS language with one click configuration for Mobile Analytics.